# iOS inapp-purchase, server notification status GRACE_PERIOD

Tags: php, ios, laravel, in-app-purchase

Implementing iOS server notification with laravel. I am unable to get notificationType 'DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW' and subtype 'GRACE_PERIOD'.
I already set grace period inside App -> subscription -> Grace period.
I am getting notificationType 'DID_RENEW'around 13 time, then my subscription directly goes to notificationType 'EXPIRED', without going in 'GRACE_PERIOD'.

In my laravel application i am getting all statuses, except 'GRACE_PERIOD', Inside server notification i am expecting notificationType 'DID_FAIL_TO_RENEW' and subtype 'GRACE_PERIOD'

Comment: I don't believe the sandbox simulates grace periods. The grace period occurs when subscription renewal fails due to a billing problem. The sandbox simulates renewals followed by cancellation.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you send a official documentation link?

Comment: I don't know if there is any official document. All I know is what I have observed over the years and that the way subscription testing works in the sandbox predates the server api and grace periods

Comment: Found this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox/testing_an_auto-renewable_subscription

Comment: And this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox/testing_failing_subscription_renewals_and_in-app_purchases - maybe this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a way of enabling the grace period in the test environment for auto-renewable subscriptions by using SKTestSession
and setting billingGracePeriodIsEnabled to true. You can read more about SKTestSession here:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekittest/sktestsession